# Regex pattern matching with multiple strings

Tags: java, python-3.x, regex, java-8, pattern-matching

Forgive me. I am not familiarized much with Regex patterns.

I have created a regex pattern as below.

```
String regex = Pattern.quote(value) + ", [NnoneOoff0-9\\-\\+\\/]+|[NnoneOoff0-9\\-\\+\\/]+, "
            + Pattern.quote(value);
```

This regex pattern is failing with 2 different set of strings.

value = "207e/160";

***Use Case 1*** -

When `channelStr = "207e/160, 149/80"`

Then `channelStr.matches(regex)`, returns "true".

***Use Case 2*** -

When `channelStr = "207e/160, 149/80, 11"`

Then `channelStr.matches(regex)`, returns "false".

Not able to figure out why? As far I can understand it may be because of the multiple spaces involved when more than 2 strings are present with separated by comma.

Not sure what should be correct pattern I should write for more than 2 strings.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you print your pattern, it is:

```
\Q207e/160\E, [NnoneOoff0-9\-\+\/]+|[NnoneOoff0-9\-\+\/]+, \Q207e/160\E
```

It consists of an alternation `|` matching a mandatory comma as well on the left as on the right side.

Using matches(), should match the whole string and that is the case for `207e/160, 149/80` so that is a match.

Only for this string `207e/160, 149/80, 11` there are 2 comma's, so you do get a partial match for the first part of the string, but you don't match the whole string so matches() returns false.

See the matches in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eRhOu2/1).

---

To match all the values, you can use a repeating pattern:

```
^[NnoeOf0-9+/-]+(?:,\h*[NnoeOf0-90+/-]+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[NnoeOf0-9\\+/-]+`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,\h*` Match a comma and optional horizontal whitespace chars
  - `[NnoeOf0-90-9\\+/-]+` Match 1+ any of the listed in the character class
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it (if there should be at least 1 comma, then the quantifier can be `+` instead of `*`)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9P78QL/1)

Example using matches():

```
String channelStr1 = "207e/160, 149/80";
String channelStr2 = "207e/160, 149/80, 11";
String regex = "^[NnoeOf0-9+/-]+(?:,\\h*[NnoeOf0-90+/-]+)*$";
        
System.out.println(channelStr1.matches(regex));
System.out.println(channelStr2.matches(regex));
```

Output

true
true

**Note** that in the character class you can put `-` at the end not having to escape it, and the `+` and `/` also does not have to be escaped.

Comment: A good practice is not to duplicate a (long) subexpression, if possible. First, because it can be altered, as is the case with the class defined in this expression, and second, because it makes maintenance more laborious and delicate.

Comment: @JGomez Repeating the subexpression here is because it is an unrolled pattern. Java does not support recursion a sub pattern, or else you could do that. The pattern that you suggest, has a single character class, but repeating the whole expression and using the negative lookahead and quantifiers can introduce more backtracking when there is not match.  See for example the number of steps (which eventually might be internally optimized by Java)  https://regex101.com/r/bBkUg3/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your RegEx. it has a description of everything that's going on to help with debugging. They have a quick reference section bottom right that you can use to figure out what you can do with examples and stuff.

A few things, you can add literals with `\`, so `\"` for a literal double quote.

If you want the pattern to be one or more of something, you would use `+`. These are called quantifiers and can be applied to groups, tokens, etc. The token for a whitespace character is `\s`. So, one or more whitespace characters would be `\s+`.

It's difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but hopefully pointing you to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) will help. If you want to provide examples of the current RegEx you have, what you want to match and then the strings you're using to test it I'll be happy to provide you with an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:[NnoneOoff0-9\\-\\+\\/]+ *(?:, *(?!$)|$))+$
```

`^` Start
`(?: ... )` Non-capturing group that defines an item and its separator. After each item, except the last, the separator (,) must appear. Spaces (one, several, or none) can appear before and after the comma, which is specified with  `*`. This group can appear one or more times to the end of the string, as specified by the `+` quantifier after the group's closing parenthesis.

[Regex101 Test](https://regex101.com/r/y4EWZi/1)

[image]